# Async function not saving in database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, mern

This function is supposed to save the cart state to my database.
Well I guess I'm supposed to call await Axios .post to save the data in my database but I have no idea how to do this and I've been googling for an hour 
   This is on client-side everything works fine with  postman on the backend

```
  sendCart = async cart => {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        };

        try {
           const res = await axios.post('/api/purchase', cart, config)


        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
      }

typeError: req.body.map is not a function
at router.post (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\routes\Purchase.js:7:24)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:9





MongoDb Connected
TypeError: req.body.map is not a function
at router.post (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\routes\Purchase.js:7:24)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at jsonParser (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7)
TypeError: req.body.map is not a function
at router.post (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\routes\Purchase.js:7:24)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at jsonParser (C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\VBackend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7)
```

This is my route

```
const express = require("express");
const models = require("../models/Cart");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const newPurchase = new models.cartModel({
    products: req.body.map(element => {
      const { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count } = element;
      return { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count };
    })
  });

  newPurchase
    .save()
    .then(purchase => res.json(purchase))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little bit better? Add some more detail about your problem, and explain to us what your desired result is. That would greatly help us who are trying to solve your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Im not getting an error its just not saving in the database

Comment: in the tutorial im doing he is using use reducer but i do not want to use this i just want to call the payload from the function

Comment: This code is from the client side. Where is the server side code? In the server is where the actual database write happens. Something like this: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2019/02/building-rest-api-mongodb-mongoose-nodejs/

Comment: everything works on the server side i used postamn but i cant get the client side to save which i posted

Comment: Did you set the baseURL in axios? something like http://localhost:3001

Comment: I set a proxy in the json file if thats what you mean.

Comment: so did you check the `res.data` value to see if there is what you expect? are you just not seeing it on the client side or is it actually not saving in the database?

Comment: Res.data is fine but its just not saving in the database

Comment: ok so you're probably passing the data differently than how you are in postman. can you look at server logs when you post to see what you're getting

Comment: How do i look at server logs?

Comment: On postman or client side?

Comment: the sever process, print out or log incoming requests to look at the values

Comment: I updated this with the error i get when i run the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so i actually wasnt passing the cart data through the function correctly so everything was correct in the first place.

```
sendCart = async cart => {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }

        try {
          const res = await axios.post('/api/purchase',cart, config)
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how your code is different to the one in the question? How does your code solve the problem?